# How can I combine four "quarter pages" into one fullsize page using iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, itext

I want to create four repeating "templates" on a single PDF page. The "static" info in each quarter page will be the same, but there will be variable content that differs in each one. You can think of it as four "copies" of a login form or some such, but with the entries programmatically added, such as:

```
Real name: B. Clay Shannon
User name: Radicalia
Password: thatDarnedKatzenjammer
Email address: clay@pigeon.com

Real name: Albert L.B. Kollenborn
User name: Grandpa
Password: caseyJonesBigBrother1907
Email address: princealbertinacan@balpeenhammer.org
```

(with another two at the right)

I have code to create a document and add a paragraph like so:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 25, 25))
    {
        using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
        {
            doc.Open();

            Paragraph realName = new Paragraph("Real name:", 
times16BoldCyan);
            doc.Add(realName);
            . . .
```

This sort of thing works for a "normal" page, but in the scenario described above (four quarter pages stuffed into one page), how should I go about it? Should it be something like this:

```
    using (var msNorthWestQuadrant = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var docNorthWestQuadrant = new Document(PageSize.A4, 6.25, 
6.25, 6.25, 6.25))
        {
            using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(docNorthWestQuadrant, 
            msNorthWestQuadrant))
            {
                docNorthWestQuadrant.Open();

                Paragraph realName = new Paragraph("Real name:", 
times16BoldCyan);
                docNorthWestQuadrant.Add(realName);
                . . .

        using (var msNorthEastQuadrant = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var docNorthEastQuadrant = new Document(PageSize.A4, 
12.5, 12.5, 6.25, 6.25))
            {
                using (var writer = 
PdfWriter.GetInstance(docNorthEastQuadrant, msNorthEastQuadrant))
                {
                    docNorthEastQuadrant.Open();

                    Paragraph realName = new Paragraph("Real name:", 
times16BoldCyan);
                    docNorthEastQuadrant.Add(realName);
                    . . .
```

(etc. - with SouthEastQuadrant and SouthEastQuadrant, too?)

...or is that the wrong approach? If it is, what are the precise values I need for the PageSize locations/sizes (the "1.25"s above are just a wild guess).

### UPDATE

Or would it be that I need a "master" doc object, and then four "sub" doc objects that are added to the master like so (pseudocode):

```
using (var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 25, 25))

using (var docNorthwest = new Document(PageSize.A4, 6.25, 6.25, 6.25, 6.25))
. . .
docNorthwest.Add(par);
doc.Add(docNorthwest);
. . .
using (var docSouthwest = new Document(PageSize.A4, 6.25, 6.25, 6.25, 6.25))
docSouthwest.Add(par2);
doc.Add(docSouthwest);
. . .
using (var docSoutheast = new Document(PageSize.A4, 6.25, 6.25, 6.25, 6.25))
docSoutheast.Add(par3);
doc.Add(docSoutheast);
. . .
using (var docNortheast = new Document(PageSize.A4, 6.25, 6.25, 6.25, 6.25))
docNortheast.Add(par2);
doc.Add(docNortheast);
. . .
```

Comment: The question is actually very broad. Have you considered using AcroForm templates for the content that never changes? I'd use some desktop tool to create such a template, and then use iText to import that template into each page 4 times and to stamp the variable content at the appropriate places (based on the positions of the AcroForm fields). That would be the simplest approach, but unfortunately, it means that you have to throw away all the code you've written so far.

Comment: I've written very little so far; that was pseudocode above based on an existing bit of iTextSharp code I have from yesteryear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the description above, a simple way to accomplish your goal:

1. Create a single in-memory `Document`
2. Put the repeating content on separate pages of the `Document`
3. Dump the individual pages from the original `Document` into  a new `Document` using a `PdfPTable`

First, some test data for steps 1-2 above:

```
byte[] GetMasterDocument(int count)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var document = new Document())
        {
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
            document.Open();
            for (int i = 1; i <= count; ++i)
            {
                document.Add(new Paragraph(string.Format(
@"Real name: real-name-{0:D4}
User name: user-name-{0:D4}
Password: password-{0:D4}
Email address: email-{0:D4}@invalid.com",
                 i)));
                if (i < count) document.NewPage();
            }
        }
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Dump the repeating content into the output file:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(GetMasterDocument(38));
Rectangle pageSize = reader.GetPageSize(1);
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(
    outputFile,
    FileMode.Create,
    FileAccess.Write))
{
    using (Document document = new Document(pageSize, 0, 0, 0, 0))
    {
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
        document.Open();
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
        table.TotalWidth = pageSize.Width;
        table.LockedWidth = true;
        table.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
        table.DefaultCell.FixedHeight = pageSize.Height / 2;

        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
            table.AddCell(Image.GetInstance(page));
        }
        document.Add(table);
    }
}
```

If the repeating content is as small as above, and there's too much empty space, (pages are scaled to fit `PdfPCell`) set a smaller page size in `GetMasterDocument()`. `PageSize.A6` works pretty well with the sample data above:

[image]

Comment: Good answer! Thanks!