# How can I increase the font size while generating a PDF file using this code?

Tags: c#, pdf, fonts, itext

I got a working answer to my question on printing four "quarter page" sections on one fullsize page with iTextSharp [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35959487/how-can-i-combine-four-quarter-pages-into-one-fullsize-page-using-itextsharp).

The problem is that the print is sort of puny; here's an example of the top half of a page - you can see how small the print is as well as how much extra space is available:

[image]

This is the code that is used, based on the answer provided on the heretofore linked SO post:

```
public static void PrintSlips(List<AssignmentStudentMashup> asmList)
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(GetMasterDocument(asmList));
    Rectangle pageSize = reader.GetPageSize(1);
    string printedDate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
    printedDate = printedDate.Replace("/", "_");
    string printedSlipsFile = $"C:\\AYttFMApp\\AYttFMSlips_{printedDate}.pdf";

    // Delete the file if it exists.
    if (File.Exists(printedSlipsFile))
    {
        File.Delete(printedSlipsFile);
    }

    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(
        printedSlipsFile,
        FileMode.Create,
        FileAccess.Write))
    {
        using (Document document = new Document(pageSize, 0, 0, 0, 0)) // pageSize could be replaced with "A4"
        {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
            document.Open();
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2)
            {
                TotalWidth = pageSize.Width,
                LockedWidth = true
            };
            table.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
            table.DefaultCell.FixedHeight = pageSize.Height / 2;

            for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
            {
                PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
                table.AddCell(Image.GetInstance(page));
            }
            document.Add(table);
        }
    }
}

internal static byte[] GetMasterDocument(List<AssignmentStudentMashup> asmList)
{
    int count = asmList.Count;
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var document = new Document())
        {
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
            document.Open();
            for (int i = 1; i < count; ++i)
            {
                document.Add(new Paragraph(
                    $@"WeekOfAssignment: {asmList[i].WeekOfAssignment}
                      TalkTypeName: {asmList
                        [i].TalkTypeName}
                      StudentFullname: {asmList[i]
                            .StudentFullname}
                      AssistantFullname: {asmList[i]
                                .AssistantFullname}
                      CounselPointNum: {asmList[i]
                                    .CounselPointNum}
                      CounselPointStr: {asmList[i
                                        ].CounselPointStr}"));
                if (i < count) document.NewPage();
            }
        }
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

I assume the place to increase the font would be somewhere in GetMasterDocument(), but I don't know where/what to do. Also, I would like to bold the first portion of each line (the part that precedes the ":").

### UPDATE

I tried Agus Rdz's suggestion from the link he provided:

```
BaseFont bfCourier = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.COURIER, BaseFont.CP1252, false);
Font courier = new Font(bfCourier, 12, Font.BOLD, Color.Black);
. . .
CounselPointStr: {asmList[i
    //].CounselPointStr}"));
      ].CounselPointStr}", courier));
```

...but that won't compile; I get:

*Error  CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont' to 'iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily'*

...and:

*Error  CS1503  Argument 4: cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Color' to 'iTextSharp.text.BaseColor'   AYttFMScheduler*

So I then tried this, based on a comment added to that blog post:

```
Font fMSGothic = FontFactory.GetFont("MS-PGothic", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, 16);
. . .
CounselPointStr: {asmList[i
    //].CounselPointStr}"));
      ].CounselPointStr}", courier));
```

...which compiles, but with that I get an I/O Exception, more specifically "*Document has no pages*"

Comment: As a regular visitor of StackOverflow, you should know that it's not done to change a question after you've received a valid answer. The issue with the fonts was sufficiently addressed, but you changed the question to an ordinary "document has no pages" question. As a result, the title of the question no longer corresponds with its body. That's misleading (and also the reason why you shouldn't change the essence of a question once it has been posted). Please let's keep StackOverflow clean.

Comment: No, my question is still the same; I was just mentioning how an attempt to address that problem did not work.

Comment: The question "How can I increase the font size?" has been solved: you were creating the `Font` object incorrectly. To increase the font size, just change `12` (for a 12pt font) into a bigger number, e.g. `24` (to make it double as big). Your new question is "why do I get a *document has no pages* error." That's a *different* problem. People who see the title "How do I increase the Font size" will not realize that, in reality, you aren't adding any content to your document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
BaseFont bfCourier = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.COURIER, BaseFont.CP1252, false);
Font courier = new Font(bfCourier, 12, Font.BOLD, Color.Black);
```

In the first line, you create a `BaseFont` object. You can use that object to create a `Font` like this:

```
Font courier = new Font(bfCourier, 12);
```

If you want the font to be bold, you can create a `BaseFont` like this:

```
BaseFont bfCourier = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.COURIER_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, false);
```

The error you had, was caused by the fact that a `Font` can also be create in a different way:

```
Font courier = new Font(Font.FontFamily.COURIER, 12, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
```

You confused the concept of `BaseFont` and `FontFamily`. A font family (e.g. Courier) is a family of fonts consisting of different fonts (Courier regular, Courier bold, Courier italic, Courier bold-italic). A base font is a single font (e.g. Courier bold).

Note that you also mixed up the classes `Color` and `BaseColor`. Actually, the error messages you got were pretty self-explaining.

The "Document has no pages" error also explains what goes wrong: when you `Close()` the document, no content was added. Maybe you *think* you've added content, but you didn't. If you think you did, the most likely cause is another exception that got thrown. For instance: you've used a font that doesn't exist. An `IOException` occurs and you ignore it. As a result, no text is added and you get a "Document has no pages" error. Or, you try to add an `Image` but the path to that images is wrong. As a result, no content is added and you get a "Document has no pages" error.

In your case, you may get that error because `asmList` is empty. In that case, you are creating a document without any content because there are no students in `asmList`.